# installing oracle on linux red hat 5

Tags: java, oracle, redhat

while installing oracle on linux red hat 5 its giving java.lang error how can i get rid of it?

Comment: You're a long way from The Perfect Question: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Installing Oracle? I cannot install a company ^O). What exactly (application) are you installing?

Comment: Please post the complete error message/stack trace.

Comment: You could install Windows?  Usually helps.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of applications on RHE5 throwing Java errors (assuming Java is found at all) is the default Red Hat Enterprise install that points **/usr/bin/java** at **/etc/alternatives/java** and thence to a RH-provided non-Sun/Oracle Java.

For maximum compatibility, install the version of Oracle Java recommended by the application's install notes. Delete /etc/alternatives/java and recreate it soft-linked to this Java.

Comment: oh god, mangling the Linux alternatives setup for your own purposes is such a bad idea.  Please don't.

Comment: Hundreds of happy servers and counting...